# Using two JsonSerializers for single entity in Jackson

Tags: java, jackson, resteasy

I've found a way to implement my own serialization method extending the `JsonSerializer<Foo>`, overriding the `serialize()` method and registering the `SimpleModule` with everything. Here is what I have:

```
@Provider
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class JacksonConfig implements ContextResolver<ObjectMapper> {


    @Override
    public ObjectMapper getContext(Class<?> aClass) {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
        SimpleModule fooModule = new SimpleModule("FooModule",
                                      new Version(0, 1, 0, null, "org.foo.bar", "foo"));
        relationshipModule.addSerializer(Foo.class, new FooJacksonSerializer());
        relationshipModule.addDeserializer(Foo.class, new FooJacksonDeserializer());
        mapper.registerModule(fooModule);
        return mapper;
    }
}
```

However, is there a way to use two custom serialization strategies and depending on the REST request (I use RestEasy) choose the right one? I.e. changing it programmaticaly on the fly, not when the context is set-up. I'd like to have a concise form of the `Foo` and the verbose one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could implement a special ObjectMapper and manually obtain the one you need:

```
@Provider
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class JacksonConfig implements ContextResolver<ObjectMapper> {

    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    private SpecialObjectMapper specialObjectMapper; // a class extending ObjectMapper

    public JacksonConfig() {
        objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        // configuration ...
        specialObjectMapper = new SpecialObjectMapper();
        // configuration with module ...
    }

    @Override
    public ObjectMapper getContext(Class<?> clazz) {
        return clazz == SpecialObjectMapper.class ? specialObjectMapper : objectMapper;
    }

}
```

In your resource class:

```
@Context 
private Providers providers;

public String get() {
    ContextResolver<ObjectMapper> contextResolver = 
        providers.getContextResolver(ObjectMapper.class, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE);
    ObjectMapper mapper = someCondition 
        ? contextResolver.getContext(SpecialObjectMapper.class) 
        : contextResolver.getContext(ObjectMapper.class);
    return mapper.writeValueAsString(value);
}
```

I don't know what your goal is but maybe you can also achieve it with [Jackson's JSON Views](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonJsonViews) or define a custom MediaType like `application/vnd.com.foo.bar.foo+json` and register your serializer only for this type.

Comment: Thanks, the views look promising, because the JAX-RS methods can be annotated with them. Unfortunately, my use case is little bit more complicated, it's not only about hiding certain fields in the entity, but about rendering them differently. Is there a way to set custom serializer for certain view?

Comment: Rendering them differently sounds like a different representation so a custom MediaType should fit here?

Comment: It's json-ld(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON-LD) the mime type should be normal application/json but it's quite verbose, so I want also some consise way of the same data.

I ended up with your original suggestion, thanks a lot!

Comment: Not sure if I understood you correctly: Your special serializer serializes json-ld while the normal one serializes normal json but you want to use the same MimeType for both?

Comment: yes, MimeType of both should be the same. Here is what I ended up with http://git.io/vLrIK . Thanks, once again

Comment: Don't want to bother you too much here but why don't you use two Content-Types? You would'nt add a query-param isXml if the client wants xml, would you? If you map your serializer to `application/ld+json` the rest will be handled by the magic of Content-Negotiation :)

Comment: I was considering this option as well, the thing is that it is a JSON. And the  `application/ld+json` mime type is not so common. Technically it's a special type of json while xml != json. Perhaps, real RESTafarians handle this by different REST representations using the content negotiation, but this approach has also benefit that the API is browsable in browser (providing some json visualization extension is installed)